# Autoscan autoconf generated configure script can't find cmath functions in c++ code

Tags: c++, g++, autotools, autoconf

I'm confused why a configure script generated by autoscan and autoconf tells me it can't find the functions `pow` and `sqrt` in a c++ code that includes the `cmath` header file. I am calling `AC_CHECK_FUNCS([pow sqrt])` (which returns a "no" answer). The code compiles and runs just fine, no errors whatsoever.

C++ code:

```
#include <cmath>
...
x = sqrt(y);
```

configure.ac:

```
AC_CHECK_FUNCS([pow sqrt])
```

There are no library checks, but I don't need to link `-lm` on the command line for cmath. I'm not sure if this is the holdup. Seems fairly simple, so I'm confused why it's not working. FYI, g++ 4.1.2, autoconf 2.59, RedHat EL 5.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are compiling C++ code you should switch autoconf to run its tests with C++, e.g. add

```
AC_LANG(C++)
```

before your checks. This will run the tests with C++, but still only check existence of the corresponding C function. See [caveats here](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/info2www?%28autoconf.info%29Generic%20Functions).

Comment: That worked. Thanks. It's been a while since I autoconfiscated, and this may be the first time I've done it to a C++ program.